# Excel / Powerquery: reshape and transpose part of a table

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a table like this that i built using powerquery with lots of data from different places.

[image]

Now i'm stuck trying to transpose part of this while leaving the main column as is.
I need to change this to the below format for further processing by a different script i cannot change.

[image]

It can be simple excel or powerquery, even as VB script please. Anything that can do the trick.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following in Power Query:

1) unpivot columns other than Customer and Month

2) pivot Month with Value as value column

as in the code below

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Customer", type text}, {"Month", type text}, {"Revenue", type number}, {"Product 1", type number}, {"Product 2", type number}, {"Product 3", type number}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Customer", "Month"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Month]), "Month", "Value", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: perfect, that was really quick and easy. Not sure how i couldn't find the unpivot some columns option. thanks